# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto with auto does not add new column

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

After I add `@Embedded` with `BigDecimals`:

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildGrossNetTransformVariables {

@Column(name = "amount", precision = 19, scale = 4)
public BigDecimal amount;
...
```

Usage in another entities:

```
@Embedded
protected ParentGrossNetTransformVariables grossNetTransform;
```

`lConf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "auto")` stoped working (I need argument "auto" but I checked also `lConf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop")` and with "create-drop" argument the database was created properly). When I try to add new column to check if column autoupdate works:

```
@Type(type="java.lang.String")
@Column(name = "test")
protected String test;
```

The error

```
SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: the Column this._test doesnt exist
```

**Can i debug it somehow?**

I tried `lConf.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");` but the first log is `SELECT ...` statement instead of `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is not valid value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` you really mean `update`. Try again.